# Using sftp to get directories and only specified files within them

Tags: bash, sftp

I have a directory that contains a number of folders within it that all contain files of the same name:

```
folder1
   file1.txt
   file2.txt
folder2
   file1.txt
   file2.txt
```

Is there a way to use sftp to get all the folders but such that they only contain file1.txt such that the output will look like this:

```
folder1
   file1.txt
folder2
   file1.txt
```

I tried `get -r */*/'file1.txt'` but this just overwrites each copy of file1.txt.

Comment: not really. get's syntax is `get source dest`. if dest is a directory, you can get multiple files, and they'll all go into that directory. if it's a file, then whatever you fetch goes into that one single file. get will not do "parallel" copies of multiple files into multiple destinations.

Comment: @MarcB that's kinda what I expected. Thanks.

Comment: yes, you'll have to manage that in your script AND it will (probably) require 2 passes, 1 to get the dirs/files, and 2 (using variable manipulation) create a local file like `folder1_file1.txt; folder2_file1.txt` . Or of course, build a parallel dir structure on your recieving side to mimic the source. Good luck.